# Is this sentence correct? ( adj+noun order)

Tags: word-usage, word-order, syntactic-analysis, academia

"...possibly generated by the **damages intensification** of the hexagonal lattice caused by the repeated impact of the steel balls during the milling process."
First of all, from my point of view, *damage* is an uncountable word, so I don't know if *damages* is correct. I was wondering if one of these ways of rephrasing that sentence is more correct: “intensification of damage of the hexagonal lattice” or “intensified damage of the hexagonal lattice”. What do you think? Thank you very much indeed for your help.

Comment: This is highly technical material. Thus how “damages intensification” is used cannot be inferred from standard English. However, *damages* is often plural in legal contracts and settlements.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have seen "damages" used in legal texts, but I wonder if it is correct in this case...